# how to transmit a location data without using internet?

Tags: location

I would like to send current location of a vehicle to a vehicle presence checking device. In normal case the systems send the location data over GSM Network, but I don't want this because I would like to create a cheap monitoring system. Then I cant use RF transmitter because it transmit data over a few meters. So how to transmit a location data from a gps device to a monitoring device over a 2km distance using wireless data transmission without using internet?

Answer (score 0):

If it is just internet you don't want to use, u can use phone sms to send the co-ordinates in text form.
Otherwise, a point to point network using nano stations,is the only wireless communication that I know can work even to 5km.